# Increase the max size of a file

Tags: linux

I have a file in one of my file server named 'root' in /var/spool/mail. This does not grow beyond 50 MB. I would need to increase that to 100 MB, so that it can store more logs.

Basically it's a sync log file which is very important for us. I'm not a linux techie however I tried with the truncate command, but that serves me a different purpose. I also went through multiple articles here, but I couldn't get the answer I want. Please help!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please be aware that `/var/spool/mail/root` is **not a log file**, but rather the **mailbox for root**. The majority of email messages are typically the email messages that get sent by by the cron daemon when a scheduled cron job generates standard output. I you want to properly log something, adjust the cron job to redirect the output you want to record to an actual log file.

Answer (score 0):

You should not be using this file for logs, this is not what this file is for. As @HBruijn pointed out, the `/var/spool/mail/root` file is actually a mailbox for the `root` user.

If you want to log something, send the log contents to a file in `/var/log/<application name>`.

Answer (score 0):

If you are running sendmail you can alias root to a regular email account.

```
sudo vim /etc/aliases
-- or --
sudo nano /etc/aliases
```

remove the # (hash symbol) from the beginning of the line that says root and then edit the user name that follows it. I think default it will say:
#root     mark

Then when done editing the file, you can run:
sudo newaliases

This only works for sendmail, I don't know if there is a way to redirect roots email for other MTA's.